# Hyperledger composer pii-network sample AuthorizeAccess transaction doesn't work

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I want to test pii-network sample of hyperledger composer. I can add two participants but when I want to sumbit the AuthorizeAccess transaction I get this error: "Instance admin has a property named authorized which is not declared in org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin".

Comment: Please provide more details, such as code, sample runs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

this may have been an error you saw in Playground. Please update (ie re-install) your Composer dev environment to the current release v0.15.0 (as of Nov 10th) and this problem will be resolved (in 0.14.3 specifically, there was a temporary issue with transactions ie in the Playground only). You will need to install the modules as per the docs -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html - this will get the latest release. Make sure you do a full teardown using the scripts you downloaded in `fabric-tools` (as your CC containers will be 0.14.3 or earlier and thus out of date) and that you then subsequently, do an `npm -g uninstall` of the same module names eg `composer-cli`, `composer-playground` etc and such that they are all at the same level (0.15.0) upon subsequent `npm -g install` of same composer modules.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you have connected to the business network as the "admin" identity. It is bound to the org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin participant which is a system participant and not a participant the the PII sample is expecting. 
You should issue an identity for one or more of the participants you have created in the PII network, then switch to using one of those participants before you attempt the authorizeAccess transaction.
The PII example could benefit from improved ACL rules to stop this error by only allowing the right type of participant to submit that transaction

Comment: That worked from the playground, but I wanted to issue identity from composer cli and I use this comand: composer identity issue -c admin@pii-network -f memberAcard -u memberA -a "resource:org.acme.pii.Member#memberA@acme.org"
and I git this error: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]. I think this is because my admin has a enrolment secret but in new version of composer there is no option for mentioning secret.

Comment: When creating a card or having a card generated on the deploy or start command you have to specify the secret. Can you provide more detail about why you don't think you provided a secret.